# How do I get the Volume from this json file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

EDIT: I understand that I'm basically asking someone to walk me through this. I really have no idea what to do here. Any help would be welcome.

I'm trying to pull the "volume" from the json file at http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=singlemarketdata&marketid=273. I cannot figure out how to do this though, and this is the best code I could come up with.

```
    import requests, time

    #Setting initial coin balances
    BTC=100
    LTC=0
    ALN=0

    response = requests.get("http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=singlemarketdata&marketid=273")

    volume = response.json() ["success":"markets":"volume"]
    print(volume)
```

Here is the traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CryptsyArb.py", line 10, in 
    volume = response.json() ["success":"markets":"volume"]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice

Answer (score 0):

You first need to get the response into JSON form:

```
j = response.json()
```

Then just traverse the dictionary to volume:

```
j["return"]["markets"]["ALN"]["volume"]
u'2625.71894522'
```

Notice that the output is in string format which you'll likely need to convert to numeric.